# How do I center an object inside Tikzcd right triangle?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

So I have the following Tikzcd diagram and I am trying to place a Y in the center of the triangle W, (X x Y), X or the triangle W, (X x Y), (X x Y) x Z

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
    X
    &
    & W 
        \ar[lldd, "(f'\times g')" description, dashed]  
        \ar[dd, "(f'\times g')\times g" description, dashed]
        \ar[rdd, "g"]
        \ar[ll, "f'"']
    & 
\\
    &Y
    &Y
    &
\\
    (X\times Y) 
        \ar[uu, "\pi_X"]
    &
    & (X\times Y)\times Z 
        \ar[ll, "p_{X\times Y}"]
        \ar[r, "p_Z"']
    & Z
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

I have tried adding more rows and columns. But it seems that tikz-cd makes it so that the column spacing isn't uniform, it takes way too many rows and columns to be practical. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remember the nodes and use an overlay to draw the desired nodes at the barycenters of the triangles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large,remember picture]
    |[alias=X]| X
    &
    & |[alias=W]| W 
        \ar[lldd, "(f'\times g')" description, dashed]  
        \ar[dd, "(f'\times g')\times g" description, dashed]
        \ar[rdd, "g"]
        \ar[ll, "f'"']
    & 
\\
    &Y
    &Y
    &
\\
    |[alias=XxY]| (X\times Y) 
        \ar[uu, "\pi_X"]
    &
    & |[alias=XxYxZ]| (X\times Y)\times Z 
        \ar[ll, "p_{X\times Y}"]
        \ar[r, "p_Z"']
    & Z
\end{tikzcd}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\node (Y1) at (barycentric cs:X=1,W=1,XxY=1) {$Y$};
\draw[->] (Y1) -- (W);\draw[->] (Y1) -- (XxY);
\node (Y2) at (barycentric cs:XxYxZ=1,W=1,XxY=1) {$Y$};
\draw[->] (Y2) -- (W);\draw[->] (Y2) -- (XxY);
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By increasing the coefficients of `X` or `XxYxZ` you may move the node a bit more towards the rectangular corners.

**UPDATE**: Added connecting arrows, probably too many but it should be obvious which ones to remove.

Comment: Thanks. I know this wasn't in my original question, but is there a way to connect Y to W and (X x Y) via arrows using this method?

Comment: @WilliamOliver Done